# Merge with facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a Facebook-ghost-page.
which means - a page in facebook where nobody can see, but me, that was created automatically after clicking 'Like' on a open-graph meta-tag page. used only for tracking my likers.

The thing is - When the users will go to the address of this ghost-page - they will be redirected to the website.

But, I want it to be as a Facebook page, where people can read about the website on Facebook.

So I opened another Facebook page.
But now I have likes on the "website" and likes on the "page".
sounds not good to me.

my question is: I want to merge the two. into 1 page. currently the ghost-page has the more likes. If i will click on "Merge" under "Resources" in the ghost-page. what will happen? Will it delete my Facebook page and Every time someone will try to get to this Facebook page it will redirect him to the website instead?

Answer (score 1):

The Merge tool will delete one of the pages and move the fans on to the other page. It will mean you can move fans from one page to another. All the posts from the delete page will be lost however.

Comment: Thats ok. But Facebook says it will pass them to the one with the more fans. Since that one is the ghost-page, is that means that the facebook page will become a ghost-page? I think it will......

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the address of the "ghost-page" to a URL you control on the site, and then have that URL simply redirect users to the http://facebook.com/whatever address you want them to end up at?